# Prebid.js - Find out which tag won in header bidding auction

Tags: javascript, prebid.js, header-bidding

I am using prebid.js in order to do header bidding. My code is very simmilar to the example here:

http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/postbid.html

Starting from the row #11 in the example - I set adUnitBids, i.e. which `demand tags` will participate in the auction.

Once I have a winner in the auction (look at the line #64 in the example) I have params variable holding the auction result, e.g.
`{hb_size: "300x250", hb_pb: "0.70", hb_adid: "519325bc9adf98ef", hb_bidder: "appnexus"}`

Now I want to know which tag won. Using the value of `params.hb_bidder == "appnexus"` I can go through adUnitBids and find the one with `bidder == "appnexus"`. It's not a very illegant solution, but it makes the work done.

The issue starts wen there are more than one tag of the same partner, e.g.:

`var adUnitBids = [
        {
            bidder: 'appnexus',
            params: {
               placementId: '10433394'
            }
        },
        {
            bidder: 'appnexus',
            params: {
               placementId: '123'
            }
        },
    ]`

I will know that `appnexus` won, but not which of the tags (even the index in adUnitBids array would be totally enough for me).

I looked through the list of the available [methods in Prebid.js documentation](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html) and couldn't find one that can help me with this issue.

Any solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [`onEvent` events](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.onEvent). This should get you information about the winning adunits as they are fired off from `pbjs.renderAd`

The `bidWon`, `bidRequested` and `bidResponse` events are unique in that additional data is passed and can be passed in your inline function:

```
pbjs.que.push(function() {
    pbjs.onEvent('bidWon', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```